# Pip unable to access websites, fresh install of Python 2.7.9

Tags: python, pip, openpyxl

I just did a fresh/clean install of Python 2.7.9 to get pip (couldn't get it any other way) and now when I go to install something using it I get this error:

```
pip install openpyxl
Downloading/unpacking openpyxl
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement openpyxl
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for openpyxl
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\name\pip\pip.log
```

The error log looks similar, just many time out messages with no more information:

```
  Downloading/unpacking openpyxl
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/openpyxl/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/openpyxl/: timed out
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/openpyxl/ when looking for download links for openpyxl
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for openpyxl
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for openpyxl:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/openpyxl/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/openpyxl/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/openpyxl/: timed out
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/openpyxl/ when looking for download links for openpyxl
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement openpyxl
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir c:\users\dqa8300\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_DQA8300...
No distributions at all found for openpyxl
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1177, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for openpyxl
```

I'm assuming that this is a network thing, is there any work around?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy/firewall? Looks like you're on Windows, is that right?

Comment: What version of pip? Also if you very want to install pip use get-pip.py https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py. You are also connected to the net?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am connected to the net, yes. I have pip - I want to install something using pip.

Comment: @Joseph I would assume I am being a proxy/firewall being on a corporate campus but I wouldn't know how to confirm that. I am on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a network problem.

If you can open https://pypi.python.org/simple/openpyxl/ in your browser, then it may be some other issue.

Comment: I can open this url, so that points to it not being a network issue?

Comment: It's still a network issue, just not as simple as originally suspected.  Perhaps the proxy answer should be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are behind a firewall on your corporate campus and need a proxy to make HTTP requests outside your local network. You will need to specify your proxy server in your shell before running `pip`:

```
SET HTTPS_PROXY=<proxyHost>:<proxyPort>
SET HTTP_PROXY=<proxyHost>:<proxyPort>
```

You can also specify a proxy directly to `pip`, but I understand this feature was broken at one point:

```
pip install <package> --proxy=<proxyHost>:<proxyPort>
```

However, we cannot determine your proxy information, you will need to do that. You may have some luck with:

```
import urllib2
print urllib2.getproxies()
```