# failure to install openpyxl with pip--how to overcome proxy

Tags: python, proxy, openpyxl

I am trying to install a python library, openpyxl. I just installed python 3.6 on my windows 10 work computer. The result of my installation attempt is below.

I found a related question: [pip install and custom index url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559638/pip-install-and-custom-index-url)

If my problem is use of a proxy, is there something I can do to install openpyxl anyway?

> C:\Users\00168070>pip install openpyxl
>
> Collecting openpyxl
>     Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError>(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/openpyxl/
>
> Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/openpyxl/
>
> Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/openpyxl/
>
> Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/openpyxl/
>
> Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/openpyxl/
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openpyxl (from versions: )
>
> No matching distribution found for openpyxl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip unable to access websites, fresh install of Python 2.7.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267024/pip-unable-to-access-websites-fresh-install-of-python-2-7-9)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your local network status can not resolve the host name. Maybe be you can try to install that from source, below is my step:

1:Download the source code:

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl
```

2:Build and install:

```
python3.6 setup.py install
```

3:Output:

```
.........
creating dist
creating 'dist/openpyxl-2.5.0-py3.6.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing openpyxl-2.5.0-py3.6.egg
creating /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/openpyxl-2.5.0-py3.6.egg
Extracting openpyxl-2.5.0-py3.6.egg to /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Adding openpyxl 2.5.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/openpyxl-2.5.0-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for openpyxl==2.5.0
Searching for et-xmlfile==1.0.1
Best match: et-xmlfile 1.0.1
Adding et-xmlfile 1.0.1 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Searching for jdcal==1.3
Best match: jdcal 1.3
Adding jdcal 1.3 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Finished processing dependencies for openpyxl==2.5.0
```

4:Import and using:

```
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  6 2017, 08:44:35)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from openpyxl import Workbook
>>>
```

Comment: This worked. By downloading the source code myself, I got around whatever was blocking pip's automated attempt to do so.
Note: in windows, I downloaded the source code, a tar.gz file. Then I extracted it. Then, from command prompt, I went to the extracted folder. From there, the command I used was:

setup.py install

Comment: I had this problem when behind a corporate proxy, and was able to install the package by connecting to a different (approved !) network.

Comment: Is below error relates to proxy block:
"...
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for et_xmlfile
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('et_xmlfile')"

Answer (score 2):

Installing from the wheel worked in my case:
I had to install openpyxl on a corporate LAN server (Win) without internet
The solution is based on
https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/600
i.e.

```
pip install openpyxl-3.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl --no-index --trusted-host=None --find-links=C:\__the_whl_dir__
```

at first, this did not work, complaining about

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> et-xmlfile (from openpyxl) (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching
> distribution found for et-xmlfile

Downloading, copying et_xmlfile-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl into the same dir as above, and running the pip install again, succeeded